# Example of continuous and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

For $n\geq2$, let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f$ is continuous at some $x_0$, all partial derivatives of $f$ at $x_0$ exist, but f is not differentiable at $x_0$. How can we find such an example of a function $f$?

Comment: what is $m$? is it free to choose?

Comment: yes, m is free to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example: $f(x, y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$ is continuous and both its partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$ are $0$, since the function is constant along the $x$ and $y$ axes. But $f$ is not differentiable at $(0, 0)$, because if it were, then there ought to be a directional derivative in the direction $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$, but this is not the case, since
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h/\sqrt{2}, h/\sqrt{2}) - f(0, 0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|h|/\sqrt{2}}{h},$$
which doesn't exist. Thus $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

EDIT: As user190080 pointed out, continuity can be established by composition of continuous functions, but we can also establish it by first noting that $|x|, |y| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \|(x, y)\|$. Then,
$$|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)| = \sqrt{|x||y|} \le \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \|(x, y) - (0, 0)\|.$$
The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof follows easily from the above inequality.

Comment: more details about continuity at (0,0)?

Comment: @Matthew it is a composition of continuous functions and therefore it is itself continuous